# Andyroid wont start correctly

Tags: android, emulator

I am currently having a problem with using the Andy android emulator.

Initially I had an error when starting the program which which said there was an error in starting the render sever thread. After this I uninstalled Andy (leaving user programs and data) and re installed Andy.

After this now when I start Andy I just get stuck on the loading screen with the Andy logo and text underneath saying "your desktop mobile".

Does anyone know a solution to this and/or the previous issue I had?

Comment: Is virtualization enabled in your BIOS? Do you have hyperv, virtualbox, or any other virtual things currently running?

Comment: I did not have virualization running (I now have it enabled) and I have tried running Andy after a reboot and still stuck on the loading screen. I have being using Andy during times of having Virualbox installed and not and still had the problem occur both times (I currently do not have VirtualBox installed).